# After updating edmx Model.Designer.cs become blank

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am adding new table in database. Then for that when i am updating Edmx designer file become blank it's only contain:

> "// Seeing this comment implies that the code generation for file
>   'E:\PrognoHealth\trunk\Development\PrognoHealth\PrognoHealth_MT\PHModel.edmx'
>   // failed. See the ErrorList for details."

And error list contain like

> "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS0246  The type or
>   namespace name 'PrognoHealthEntities' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   PrognoHealth_MT E:\PrognoHealth\trunk\Development\PrognoHealth\PrognoHealth_MT\Partial\Address.cs   18
>   " error

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a clean and a rebuild. If the EDMX was working as expected before you should be good to go with a clean/rebuild.

Comment: I did already to clean/rebuild project but still it not working.

Comment: Try to delete all tables from EDMX and add them all back, that process rarely fails and if it does starting from clean will give you a clear understanding of what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Please Check your EdmxFileName.context.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your  EdmxFileName.context.cs file. Th class name must be "PrognoHealthEntities".Also check constructor name.